# Multiplying two Huge matrices using spark

Tags: matlab, scala, matrix, apache-spark, matrix-inverse

i currently learning spark. i wanted to compute the matrix W and it is defined as
`W=B*H'*inverse(R + H*B*H')` here each variable is a matrix and

1. B=eb*eb'(eb' represents transpose of eb vector) [400000 * 400000]
2. R=eo*eo'(eo' represents transpose of eb vector) [200000 * 200000]
3. H is sparse matrix [200000 * 400000]

and eb matrix size is 4000000*1 so my B matrix size 400000*400000 now the problem is storing this total file i am currently  using 4GB RAM, 500GB Disk space computer. initially i have done this in matlab by block multiplication and i am writing output to file, and my output file size is more than 300GB. and it is taking so much time after that i done by using spark it is taking less time but output file is same size.

i have used this method [matrix multiplication](http://btsxj.wordpress.com/2014/08/17/multiplication-of-matrices-on-spark-mllib/) to multiply two vectors

after computation of B matrix i am unable to compute B*H' as it requires to store them in RAM  to multiply these two matrices. when i am running above code it is giving memory exception. is there any way to do this computation with limited memory i mean with out bringing total into memory. and how to compute the inverse of huge matrix of size [200000 * 200000].

Comment: If your objective is to learn Spark don't learn how to compute inverses of large matrices.  There is extensive literature on the algorithms and techniques, theoretical and applied, used to avoid inverting large matrices.  You'd be better advised to learn about the alternatives to matrix inversion.  The mathematicians, unconcerned by practical matters,  fling their inversions around and leave it to the poor computationalists to actually solve sets of equations without inversions, which are computationally very expensive.

Comment: thank you, though i can avoid inversion but i can't avoid matrix multiplication,actually i have to do this in matlab but the data is too large so my mentor suggested me to learn spark, so i am learning spark especially for this multiplication.

Comment: There's also no need to calculate the 400,000-by-400,000 `B`. Try changing the order you perform your multiplication. E.g., `H*eb` is 200,000-by-1. The transpose of this result is equal to `eb'*H'`. Of course 200,000-by-200,000 is still big. These matrices are symmetric and could be calculated element-by-element or row-by-row with results stored in a file.

Comment: i have done up to that, after that i have applied same multiplication method its output file also is more than 100GB, but problem comes again

Answer (score 1):

If almost all entries of your matrices are 0, you might want to consider using a sparse matrix datastructure, only storing the main diagonal and a map of positions to nonzero entries.

Comment: no except H all matrices have more than 75% non zero values